# Blink.jl load(loadjs!/loadcss!/importhtml!) functions not working correctly

Tags: electron, julia, blink

I hope someone here has used the [Blink.jl](https://github.com/JunoLab/Blink.jl) package for building Julia and Electron apps.


I am having problems setting up and using it, though. The issue is with all of the functions in the api provided: **load/loadcss/loadjs/importhtml**. They do not seem to work, or I might be doing something wrong.
For example:

> loadcss!(w, "styles.css")

does not apply any of the styles in the styles files in the directory.

> importhtml!(w, 'index.html')

does not display the html page stored in the local directory. The app shows a blank screen.


I might be doing something wrong as i could not find documentation on how to use the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out why, the methods take the full path and not the relative paths, even if files are inside the same folder. So, something like this works:

> loadcss!(w, "D:\project\styles.css")

but this won't work:

> loadcss!(w, "styles.css")